# Receving the undefined method `generators' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I run the RailsTorrent(https://github.com/raskhadafi/railstorrent), I got the error below :

```
[root@sookcha railstorrent]# rails s
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `generators' for #<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x000000024eef38> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.1.2/lib/inherited_resources.rb:24:in `<class:Railtie>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.1.2/lib/inherited_resources.rb:22:in `<module:InheritedResources>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.1.2/lib/inherited_resources.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
from /root/railstorrent/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux] , Rails 3.2.3 on my CentOS 6.2 system.

I've searched the error code, but I can't find about it.

How can I solve it?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie/Configuration.html#method-i-app_generators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of `inherited_resources` (1.1.2) is not compatible with Rails 3.2.3, try updating `inherited_resources` to 1.3.1. Rails 3.1 deprecated `config.generators` in favor of `config.app_generators` and therefore has been thrown out in Rails 3.2